# nginx+php "The connection was reset" on file upload

Tags: nginx

I get an error that says "The connection was reset" immediately when I upload a file over a certain size, I think it's over around 4MB.
My web server is running on nginx, I tried set `client_max_body_size 1G` or even setting to 0, no success.

I'd be glad to hear a solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to restart the nginx service by using `sudo service nginx restart` and it solved itself!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file was bigger than the allowed size by `NGINX` in the setting "`client_max_body_size`". To change this setting open in your terminal the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and add the following inside the http section:

```
http {
  ...
  client_max_body_size 128m; #Any desired size in MB
  ...
}
```

In nginx versions from 1.0 and above, this setting is not included by default in the nginx.conf file.